# InternalError Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**InternalError Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\major project\MajorProject\Frontend\majorProject\node_modules@react-navigation': fs.js (1800:7)**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from'./Pages/Home'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/> 
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>  
        
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```